# Multiple classes in one file, Ruby Style Question

Tags: ruby, styles

I am writing a script that takes data from a database and creates GoogleChart URLs from the parsed data. I only need to create two type of charts, Pie and Bar, so is it wrong if I stick both of those classes in the same file just to keep the number of files I have low?

Thanks

Comment: Is it wrong?  Of course not, it's your code.  As long as it works for you, great! But if there's a point when the code becomes unwieldy or think you might need to add future complexity, or you're sharing it with other developers, that might be a good time to consider cleaning it up a bit.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you're asking the "ruby" way, then it is to put your classes in separate files. As some others have alluded to, placing your classes in separate files scales better. If you place multiple classes in the same file and they start to grow, then you're going to need to separate them later.

So why not have them separate from the beginning?

**UPDATE**

I should also mention that autoload works by expecting classes to be in their own files. For instance, if you're in a Rails environment and you don't separate classes into different files, you'll have to `require` the file explicitly. The best place to do this would be in the `application.rb` file. I know you're not in a Rails environment, but for others who may find this answer, maybe this info will be helpful.

**UPDATE2**

By 'autoload', I meant Rails autoload. If you configure your own autoload, you can put classes in the same file; but again, why? The Ruby and Java communities usually expect classes to be in separate files. The only exception are nested classes, but that's for more advanced design patterns.

Comment: I also want to add that multiple files enables things like CMD+T in sublime/textmate and your fuzzy file finder in VIM to work so well. If you want to find a class, CMD/CTRL+t, type the first letter of each word and pull it up in seconds. You can't necessarily do that if you have multiple classes in the same file. Worse yet, chances are you'll most likely have some classes in the same file and others that each get their own. So sometimes CMD/CTRL+T will work and other times it will just confuse you...

Answer (score 3):

Usually more less-complex files are better than less more-complex ones. Specially if you need to share the code with others.

Comment: its a script that no one besides me will probably open, they will just double click on it so it runs

Comment: I wouldn't trade maintainability for lowering the file number, unless keeping this number low is part of the scope of your problem. And I do not think its sane to try and find ways to justify not doing it The Right Way™. Break those classes in separate files already! =)

Answer (score 0):

It's not wrong.  If your code is simple enough* then by all means put all of it in one file.

On the other hand, if you think your code is going to get more complex later, or if you plan to use automated testing tools later, you will be doing yourself a big favour if you deal with the structure of all that now.

(* My personal rule of thumb: about 200 lines.)